# htaccess Redirect 301 is chaining itself

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, mod-alias

I have around 100+- redirects in a .htaccess file and some urls are chaining each other.

For example:

```
Redirect 301 /air-india-trial/air-india-promo-conditions/ /features/
```

**Goes to**

```
/trial/air-india-promo-conditions/
```

**Because of**

```
Redirect 301 /air-india-trial/ /trial/
```

So the URL is replacing '/air-india-trial/' for '/trial/' because of the 2nd redirect being called. I already tried to put `https://example.com/` before the 2nd URL in the `Redirect 301` but that doesn't work. Not sure if it matters but the URL `/air-india-trial/` doesn't exist on the new website. The domain is the same as the old website tho. Anyone that has an idea to fix those redirect chains?

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> Redirect 301 /air-india-trial/air-india-promo-conditions/ /features/
> ```
>
> Goes to
>
> ```
> /trial/air-india-promo-conditions/
> ```

Presumably you mean a *request* for `/air-india-trial/air-india-promo-conditions/` ends up being redirected to `/trial/air-india-promo-conditions/` (that *directive* doesn't "go to" anything).

> ...because of the 2nd redirect being called. I already tried to put `https://example.com/` before the 2nd url in the Redirect 301 but that doesn't work.

You can't put `https://example.com/` as part of the URL in the first argument - if that is what you are referring to? It simply won't match. It matches against the URL-path only.

Since the `Redirect` directive is *prefix-matching* (and everything after the match is copied onto the end of the target URL), you need to order your `Redirect` directives in order of specificity. The most specific (ie. longest path) redirect needs to be before the less specific redirects.

mod_alias `Redirect` directives do not "chain" together as you seem to imply.

So, in your example, the following should work to redirect `/air-india-trial/air-india-promo-conditions/` to `/features/`:

```
Redirect 301 /air-india-trial/air-india-promo-conditions/ /features/
Redirect 301 /air-india-trial/ /trial/
```

(Although you do perhaps suggest that the directives are already in order (or are you just referring to the order in your question)? In which case there is still a conflict with another directive or you are seeing a cached response.)

You will need to clear your browser cache after making this change as the 301 (permanent) redirect will be cached by the browser.

If you specifically want to redirect only `/air-india-trial/` and not `/air-india-trial/<something>` then you need to use a `RedirectMatch` directive instead, which matches against a regex and is not prefix-matching. For example:

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/air-india-trial/$ /trial/
```

Also, if you have any mod_rewrite (`RewriteRule`) redirects then these might conflict. Since different Apache modules runs independently and at different times throughout the request, you should avoid mixing redirects from both modules because of potential conflicts. (mod_rewrite will always run first on Apache 2.4, despite the apparent order of these directives in `.htaccess`.)